# Installing Open CV 2.3.1 for Visual C ++ 2010 express Windows 7 x 64

Tags: opencv

This is what I have done so far

- Downloaded Open CV 2.3.1, visual C++ and Cmake.
- I extracted all the Open CV files into open cv and created a build folder.
- Started Cmake and configured Open CV,
- Only after I left the boxes for QT, IPP and TBB "OPEN" could I generate the OpenCV.lib file.
- I also added "C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin" to the Environment Variables.
- Using Visual C++ I first opened the open cv lib file - which it successfully did- after which I compiled it.

This is what the output had to say,

> 112>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debugopencv_highgui231d.lib'
>   113>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   113>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 109 failed, 14 up-to-date, 3 skipped ==========>

I really don't know what I have done wrong. Also I am new to Visual C++.>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile OpenCV to be able to work with it.

If you download `OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack.exe`, it has pre-built binaries and lib files for Visual Studio 2010 32 and 64-bit. Look in the `/build/` subdirectory in the folder you installed OpenCV